# Setting up DNS records for my mail server - DMARC and SPF - add to all domains or just the mail server domain?

Tags: email, dns, spf, dmarc

I have a mail server with the domain mail.creoconcept.com
I have many clients that use my email service, each with their own domain. I'm setting up DMARC and SPF records for my server. I've added the following records to the domain creoconcept.com:

Host: @
Type: TXT
Content: v=spf1 mx a ip4:194.65.78.182 mx:mail.creoconcept.com -all

Host: _dmarc
Type: TXT
Content: v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@creoconcept.com;  ruf=mailto:postmaster@creoconcept.com;

But my question is: do I need to add these records to all domains that are using my email service?
The domains right now have the MX record mail.creoconcept.com. Is this enough? Will the records at creoconcept.com be reflected on the domains that have this MX record?

I know this is probably a noob question but I can't find the answer on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Both SPF & DMARC are domain specific.
As a minimum you will need to have an SPF record for each of the domains.
On this if the IP address of your mail server is as you have entered into the A record section of the SPF you can remove this value like wise for the MX value making your SPF record:

```
Host: @ Type: TXT Content: v=spf1 mx a -all
```

This is just removing any duplications from your SPF record entry. However, if the IP address '194.65.78.182' is neither your web site or your eMail server you will need to add it back in but only if it send eMails on behalf of your domain.
For example if you have a contact form on your web site.

As for the DMARC rules again you should add a rule for each domain, changing the 'rua' and 'ruf' values for each of the domains (if you want them to go to a different address'